# AOSP x86 adb secure

Tags: adb, security, custom-roms, android-x86, aosp

I'm trying to build a custom ROM with secure access via adb. My goal is to secure the android image so that it can only be accessed with a certain adb RSA key pair.

When I build AOSP with 'user' variant, adb doesn't work, cannot connect to it in x86, always get 'connection refused by host', but when I build it with another variant (userdebug or eng), adb connect with no restrictions.

How can I secure adb in order to allow connections only from clients that uses certain RSA pairs?

Comment: Have you checked that adb is running at all (is enabled)  in the non-debug builds?

Comment: I enable it manually from developer options (usb debug), but in x86 virtual machine there is no easy way to connect via USB and enable adb via tcpip. I am trying to create a custom ROM that get ADB enabled via tcpip by default and secure with specific RSA keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about this on the AOSP pages about adding [support for a new device](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device#ANDROID_VENDOR_KEYS). Briefly, it goes like this:

1. Create a key pair with `adb keypair`.
2. Put the keypair into your source tree.
3. Set the build variable `PRODUCT_ADB_KEYS` to point to the directory containing the key pair.
4. Do your build.
5. To connect to this build, once it is running on device or emulator, set the environment variable `ADB_VENDOR_KEYS` to point to the directory with the key pair.